# Adding html subsites to Drupal 7 installation

Tags: theming, subsites

Newbie here, and would appreciate any insight.  I have a Drupal 7 site and am looking to create a few small HTML subsites (e.g., Drupal site www.mykittenmittons.com, html subsite cats.mykittenmittons.com).

After creating my Drupal site on BlueHost I used their "subsite" tool. The subsite folder is automatically generated in public_html. I gave it a whirl and added my html files to the subsite folder and it seems to work. Are there any reasons to not handle html subsites in this way, or problems I could encounter? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Your question is about hosting config and not Drupal, so I'm afraid is off topic here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about BlueHost or their tools, but the normal way to do that would be along the lines of:

1. Make a folder to house your HTML-only site
2. Put your site files in the folder
3. Set your webserver (Apache/Nginx/IIS) to direct requests for subsite.mysite.com to that new folder

Drupal is not involved in any way, shape or form.

So the answer is likely that there will be no problems, however I suggest asking this question of BlueHost as it really has nothing to do with Drupal.